# USB Drive won't boot in a broken Ubuntu system

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, usb, bios

I've already asked this question, but it was put on hold, so now I'll re-ask it. 
So, my PC won't boot due to this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xuc1R.jpg) which I had gotten after installing Ubuntu 17.10, then trying to forcefully delete the Ubuntu partition.

I was told to repair the MBR on my system, which is around eight years old an uses BIOS instead of UEFI, but first of all I had to reinstall Windows 7. I already knew how to install an operating system, which I had done before. I made a bootable USB using Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool, which didn't work. I tried Rufus, UNetbootin, and a couple more I forgot. None worked. I had even tried booting Ubuntu using the same USB I installed Ubuntu on before. The weird part is that my PC  [recognises my USB drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkR70.jpg) but it still won't boot from it. I've installed operating systems onto the same computer before, I'm just not sure why it won't work this time.

Answer (score -1):

**This only will work if you installed WinRe, it comes pre-installed on Windows 10 but not on Windows 7**

try to enter WinRe mode (restart a couple times) and Under "Choose an option" tab, click "Troubleshoot" button. Then click "Advanced options" feature. In the pop-up window, choose "Command Prompt" to start to fix BCD files. . Once CMD starts, type the following commands in turn:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

Then, close Command Prompt and restart your computer

Comment: The PC I aforementioned runs on Windows 7, and I never installed WinRe.